# Neural networks: Combining ReLus and Batch normalization?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

In https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14352/how-are-deep-learning-nns-different-now-2016-from-the-ones-i-studied-just-4-ye I was told that one should use Batch normalization:

> It's been known for a while that NNs train best on data that is normalized --- i.e., there is zero mean and unit variance.

I was also told one should use ReLu neurons - especially if the inputs are images. Images usually have numbers between 0 and 1 or 0 and 255.

**Question:** Is it wise to combine ReLus with Batch normalizsation?

I would imagine that if I do first Batch normalization, I fear, one might loose information once it passes the ReLus.of have of my information once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem by combining Batch Normalization with ReLUs, this is done very often with no problems. For example the first paper about [Residual Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385) does this and obtains very good results in ImageNet classification.

Comment: Can post a link to that paper?

Comment: @Make42 Sure, Done.